# Создать Класс: Цвет (модель RGB) на С#

Tags: c#

По заданию нужно создать класса. представляющий цвет в модели rgb
Класс: Цвет (модель RGB)
Состояние (поля): красная, зеленая и синяя составляющие (значения — вещественные числа из 
промежутка [0; 1])
Методы конструирования: создание цвета в модели RGB, создание цвета в модели CMY
Свойства: красная, зеленая, синяя, cyan, magenta, yellow составляющие
Операции: сложение и вычитание
Примечание: красная, зеленая и синяя составляющие цвета, заданного в модели RGB, и cyan, 
magenta, yellow составляющие этого же цвета в модели CMY связаны соотношениями:
cyan = 1 – red;
magenta = 1 – green;
yellow = 1 – blue.

Вот мой код

```
using System;

namespace ColorRGB
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, yellow;

        Console.WriteLine("Введите составляющие цвета в модели RGB: ");
        Console.Write("Red = ");
        red = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Green = ");
        green = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Blue = ");
        blue = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        var color1 = ColorRGB.ColorRGB_RGBModel(red, green, blue);
        Console.WriteLine("Цвет rgb ({0}, {1}, {2})", color1.Red, color1.Green, color1.Blue);

        //Console.WriteLine("Введите составляющие цвета в модели CMY: ");
        //Console.Write("Cyan = ");
        //cyan = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        //Console.Write("Magenta = ");
        //magenta = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        //Console.Write("Yellow = ");
        //yellow = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        //var color2 = ColorRGB.ColorRGB_CMYModel(cyan, magenta, yellow);
        //Console.WriteLine("Цвет cmy ({0}, {1}, {2})", color1.Cyan, color1.Magenta, color1.Yellow);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class ColorRGB
{
    private ColorRGB(double _red, double _green, double _blue)
    {
        Red = _red;
        Green = _green;
        Blue = _blue;
    }

    public static ColorRGB ColorRGB_RGBModel(double _red, double _green, double _blue)
    {
        return new ColorRGB(_red, _green, _blue);
    }

    public static ColorRGB ColorRGB_CMYModel(double _cyan, double _magenta, double _yellow)
    {
        var _red = 1 - _cyan;
        var _green = 1 - _magenta;
        var _blue = 1 - _yellow;
        return new ColorRGB(_red, _green, _blue);
    }

    public double Red {
        get { return red; }
        private set { red = red < 0 ? 0 : (red > 1 ? 1 : value); }
    }
    public double Green
    {
        get { return green; }
        private set { green = green < 0 ? 0 : (green > 1 ? 1 : value); }
    }
    public double Blue
    {
        get { return blue; }
        private set { blue = blue < 0 ? 0 : (blue > 1 ? 1 : value); }
    }
    public double Cyan
    {
        get { return cyan; }
        private set { cyan = cyan < 0 ? 0 : (cyan > 1 ? 1 : value); }
    }
    public double Magenta
    {
        get { return magenta; }
        private set { magenta = magenta < 0 ? 0 : (magenta > 1 ? 1 : value); }
    }
    public double Yellow
    {
        get { return yellow; }
        private set { yellow = yellow < 0 ? 0 : (yellow > 1 ? 1 : value); }
    }

    private double red;
    private double green;
    private double blue;
    private double cyan;
    private double magenta;
    private double yellow;
}
}
```

Не могу понять, почему у меня не срабатывают проверки red = red < 0 ? 0 : (red > 1 ? 1 : value); и остальные,
если я задаю значения вне диапазона [0, 1], они и присваиваются полям?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так вы ими нигде и не пользуетесь. Вы значения цветовых компонент задаете в конструкторе, не используя ни акцессоры ни мутаторы (`get` и `set`)
Если добавить в `Main` вот такой код:

```
color1.Blue = -2;
Console.WriteLine("Цвет rgb ({0}, {1}, {2})", color1.Red, color1.Green, color1.Blue);
```

то можно увидеть, что ваши проверки работают.
Только вот `set` у вас скорее всего неправильный. Нужно что-то такое:

```
set { green = value < 0 ? 0 : (value > 1 ? 1 : value); }
```

В противном случае, установив составляющие в 0 вы сможете их изменить только со второй попытки

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, почему не используются, если у меня в конструкторе
     private ColorRGB(double _red, double _green, double _blue)
    {
        Red = _red;
        Green = _green;
        Blue = _blue;
    }    
 Как сделать так, чтобы проверки использовались?

Comment: вы знаете разницу между полем и свойством? green - это свойство. А в конструкторе вы используете поля, в частности _green. Как использовать проверки, я вам указал в ответе - смотрите второй кусок кода

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, теперь проверки работают.  
Каким образом мне нужно переписать конструктор, чтобы в нем использовались поля?

Comment: никаким. У вас и так в конструкторе используются поля. Если хотите использовать в конструкторе свойства вместо полей, то этого делать не нужно, они предназначены не для этого

Comment: Спасибо за объяснения!